# Apache cordova Visual studio 2015 Release error

Tags: android, visual-studio, cordova

After install plugin and try create simple aplication (.apk file) after click on Release get below [error](http://postimg.org/image/i1wyqqior/).

Build cmd: Command failed with exit code 1

Comment: Are you using any thirdparty phonegap plugins? Create a fresh project without installing any thirdparty plugin and check it is working fine or not.

Comment: @AvijitSarkar After install plugin get this error, blank projest work fine!

Comment: Please provide list of plugins by running `cordova plugin list`

Comment: @AvijitSarkar I'm install pushwoosh-phonegap-plugin, on second computer I'm install VS 2015 with all update after install plugin and run get this error - http://prnt.sc/b85hvw

Comment: It is working for me in command line build using Pushwoosh plugin v5.0.3 https://github.com/Pushwoosh/pushwoosh-phonegap-plugin. Can you please uninstall the plugin and reinstall it through Visual Studio https://taco.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/manage-plugins/

Comment: Also ensure you have latest version of android sdk

Comment: @AvijitSarkar how check version in VS 2015 and update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding it as an answer as it is descriptive.

Open your project folder in cmd and run `cordova plugin list`. You should get list of plugins installed in your project with version something like:

```
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.2.0 "Whitelist"    
pushwoosh-cordova-plugin 5.0.3 "Pushwoosh"
```

To check android version run `android` in cmd. It should open Andoid SDK Manager, if not then check the `PATH` in system variable. If it is fine then update these two if there is any update.

- **Android SDK Tools** and **Android SDK Platform-tools** under
  Tools
- **Android Support Repository**, **Google Play Services**, **Google Repository** under Extras